# Setting Up How to Take The Limit of a Sequence?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am taking a Calculus II course and we have just started Series and Sequences. Here is the problem:
A sequence {an} is defined as:
$$a_1 = 2,  \,\,
a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2} + \frac{1}{a_n}  
$$
Assuming that $\{a_n\}$ is convergent find its limit.

How do I make an expression to then take the limit given this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Could you say what you know about finding limits of any sequence? What techniques do you have?

Comment: Bare minimum. I understand the concepts of limits.
We have the Continuity and Convergence Theorem
Monotonic Sequence Theorem
Possibly a few others but the examples have a lot of variables that I think are causing me to over complicate it

Comment: Have you experimented to see what the limit might be? Knowing the value of the limit can be helpful in proving convergence.

Comment: I have calculated it and I see the answers underneath. My problem was the condition and where it fit into everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L$ be the limit of $a_n$, as $n\to +\infty$ (which you know it exists by assumption). Then, the limit of $a_{n+1}$ would be $L$, too (why?). Thereofre, taking the limit of both sides of

$a_{n+1} = \dfrac{a_n}{2}+\dfrac{1}{a_n}$

yields (why?)

$L = \dfrac{L}{2}+\dfrac{1}{L}$

At this point you can just solve the equation and find $L$. The initial condition is given so you can rule out one of the two possible values you get out of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a$ is the limit of $\{a_n\}$. Then it must be the case that

$$
a = \frac{a}{2} + \frac{1}{a}
$$

So $a^2 = 2 \Rightarrow a = \pm \sqrt{2}$. Notice that the initial condition is positive and if $a_n$ is positive then $a_{n+1}$ is as well. Thus

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \sqrt{2}
$$

Comment: Yes this makes sense! Thank you!